# Single quotes causing issue in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a view which is attempting to render a link with the following variable as text:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search ideas...">
   <% @ideas.each do |idea| %>
     <li>
       <%= link_to(idea.name + " for " + idea.relationship.name, idea_path(idea) ) %>
     </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

The value idea.name (retrieved from PG SQL) has a single quote in it. This is causing a javascript issue when the link is clicked:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
e.extend.globalEval jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
e.extend.globalEval jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
bp jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
e.extend.each jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
f.fn.extend.domManip jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4
f.fn.extend.append jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3
f.each.f.fn.(anonymous function) jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4
a.mobile.loadPage.a.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages.l.isSameDomain.a.ajax.success jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js:58
f.Callbacks.n jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
f.Callbacks.o.fireWith jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
w jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.d
```

I have tried to use `escape_javascript` which does not provide the proper results (puts a `\` in front of the single quote which is then rendered in the browser and the link still results in an error.

I am using Rails 3.1, jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 and jQuery 1.7.1. Any suggestions appreciated.

UPDATE: here's what the response looks like rendered in the client:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false">
   <li><a href="/ideas/34">toms shoes</a></li>
   <li><a href="/ideas/32">Toms shoes</a></li>
   <li><a href="/ideas/35">Remote controlled boat</a></li>
   <li><a href="/ideas/36">Toms Shoes</a></li>
   <li><a href="/ideas/33">Tom's shoes</a></li>
</ul>
```

It's the last item that's problematic (/ideas/33).

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid funny despite the fan boyish angle

Comment: What does the response look like to the browser?

Comment: @nnnnnn the response is the jQuery mobile processing indicator. Basically the page hangs. The javascript error that's being thrown (from chrome dev tools) is in the post.

Comment: What I meant is what does the markup in the response look like, i.e., what is the html that the browser sees as would be shown by View Page Source. (Not what does the behaviour look like to the user.)

Comment: @nnnnnn see update in the question.

Comment: You're not posting the code that'd actually be a problem. A single quote character in running text in an `<a>` element's content will not cause a JavaScript error.

Comment: This is the problematic code. The only JavaScript on the page is jquery mobile. My sense is that this is an issue with how jqm is handling the link which contains the single quote.

Comment: I think this is the issue. I'm going to try the replace suggested here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1383

Comment: That did not do it. Still puzzled by this.

Comment: Okay, I don't really like this, but it isn't the first time I've had to do this using JQM. I simply added a `rel="external"` attribute to my links and viola, no more problems. This prevents the `<a>` tag from being handled via ajax and so it behaves as a normal link.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue with jquery mobile.
I had following HTML:

```
<ul id="searchPanel" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" class="inputData" data-filter-reveal="true"
                    data-filter-placeholder="I'm looking for...">
```

JQM rendered this in DOM as:

```
<input data-type="search" placeholder="I" m="" looking="" for...'="" data-lastval="">
```

My solution was to use ’ or ′ instead of single quote '.
With reference to https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/html/entities#HTML_Entities_Table

Following are close matches to be used as an apostrophe or single quotes

```
&lsquo; OR &rsquo; OR &prime;
```

Rendered as: ‘ OR ’ OR ′ (All three are different from a single quote ' but they look alike)

So, as a workaround, you should replace the single quote in the text you get from PG SQL, and choose either of the above three characters as replacement.